# Does debugger have a load timer somewhere?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I just bought visual studio 2013, and am using the debugger.  I am wondering if there is something built in that will tell you how long something takes to load--How long a variable takes to get populated, one breakpoint to another, etc.  Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Under the debug menu, there is a performance analysis item. I have never actually used it before, but it could be useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Profilers` for such statistics.
Have look at [Analyzing Application Performance by Using Profiling Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29.aspx).
I would also recommend watching [Visual Studio 2013 Performance and Diagnostic Hub](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Visual-Studio-2013-Performance-and-Diagnostic-Hub)
For good dotnet Profilers have a look at this post : 
[What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/100490/2736559)

**As a side note:**
There are different profilers for different languages and chores, you need to specify what exactly you need, then you can pick their respective profilers.
For example if you needed to work with DataBases, you could use sqlsever profiler, or Oracle profiler,(all major DMBSs have their profilers) the same thing goes to c++, etc